# Dynamic variable name and timer name

Tags: c#, string, variables, timer

I need to have a dynamic variable and timer name, let me show you an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
Timer + resultString +_StopTime = DateTime.Parse(labelCurrentTimeValue.Text).Add(Timer_Duration);
```

resultString holds the ID of a button since I launch the same code for several timers.

I know I cannot write code that way, I just wanted to give you all the idea of what I am trying to achieve.

I also know I can use "if" or "switch case" but code will be repeated, which is what I am trying to prevent.

On the same topic I need something like that as well:

```
timer + resultString.Enabled = true;
```

For other controls I was using:

```
Control[] matches_textBoxTimer = this.Controls.Find("textBoxTimer" + resultString, true);
TextBox textBoxTimer = matches_textBoxTimer[0] as TextBox;
```

But I cannot do that with timers unfortunately, so I am looking for something similar as well.

As a last note, the variable Timer + resultString +_StopTime is already declared when I reach that code, as well as the timer.

Comment: How many timers do you have?  You could simply create a List<Timer>, or a Dictionary<string, Timer> in the Load() event of the Form.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks for the tip about titles, and so far I have 12 timers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is create a dictionary to store the timer objects, and have the key of the dictionary be a string containing the name of the timer.

```
Dictionary <String, Timer> timers;
timers["timer" + resultString].StopTime = DateTime.Parse(labelCurrentTimeValue.Text).Add(Timer_Duration);
```

In most cases, you will create a timer in the form_load method.

```
timers = new Dictionary <String, Timer>();
timers.Add(new Timer(), "timer1");
timers.Add(new Timer(), "timer2");
timers.Add(new Timer(), "timer3");

//Interval set to 1 second between ticks. 
timers["timer1"].Duration = 1000;
timers["timer2"].Duration = 1000;
timers["timer3"].Duration = 1000;

timers["timer1"].Start();
timers["timer2"].Start();
timers["timer3"].Start();
```

Comment: With this way, I must fill the dictionary with the timer names on the Form_Load() event or something similar right?

Comment: You would call timers.Add() in your program at the place where you would normal create the timer variable in code. Form_Load() would most like be the place to do this given that the timer objects should be there from the entire duration of your application. You do have the option of creating a timer after an action such as clicking a button to.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create variable names dynamically, c# is a strongly typed language. Try looking into Dictionary. I'm not sure how you would incorporate the three parts though.